# Confused with figuring out this piezoelectric sensor

Tags: sensor, piezoelectric-effect

I have [this](https://www.dytran.com/Model-5800B2-Dynapulse-Impulse-Hammer-P1445/) impulse-hammer with [this](https://www.dytran.com/images/product_pdf/5800B2_ds.pdf) specific model data-sheet.

It has output through BNC and if I hook it up to a scope or a daq board, I see nothing but some 50Hz noise when the hammer is hit. There is no direct output.

But when I use this hammer with [this amplifier](https://www.upc.edu/sct/en/documents_equipament/d_263_id-199.pdf) I get proper readings.(I don't know it is the proper type of amplifier for this hammer but it worked)

After I read [this](http://www.alliantech.com/pdf/technique/force_piez_elec.pdf) document I'm further confused.

Does this hammer have any built in amplifier in it?(Is it charge type or voltage type?) The data sheet says 100mV/LBF but I get no signal without amplifier.

What type of force sensor is it?

Comment: Well, if you have the 500lb model (10mV per pound) then you'd have to thwack something with it really hard to get a noticeable reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dedicated analog amplifier gives also the power supply. Probably is kind of DC voltage applied to BNC connector, like suppy for old style antenna amplifiers. The signal then, has to have a capacitor to isolate the DC, so you get only AC measurements. These are my tougts , only.

IN the datasheet you will find a power supply of 6mA for dedicated amplifier, and the sensor accepts 8-40mA power supply, don't know how.